# How can I determine the type of an HTML element in Jest?

Tags: javascript, html, ts-jest, jsdom

I need a way to determine the type of an HTML element in Jest. I have tried below code to see If HTMLLabelElement is available. I am getting **ReferenceError: HTMLLabelElement is not defined**

**Jest it() function code snippet**

```js
it('check HTML label Element type', async () => {
      
      const doc = document.createElement('label');

      console.log(doc instanceof HTMLLabelElement);

});
```

Let me know if anybody have any idea on this.

Comment: you can use `element.tagName`

Comment: I got your point. But is there any support for all the HTMLElements. Thats what is my concern too. Do you have idea on this?

Comment: If this is running in Node it might now have access to the dom tokens/elements in the types.  Be sure your `tsconfig.json` has `dom` listed: `"lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]` - or maybe in the ts-jest config as well

Comment: Hello @ChrisBarr, I have already tried the tsconfig.json change. I don't have any luck on that.

Comment: Protip: Your test description should be a sentence fragment that logically follows "It", as in "[It] should contain a label element". Your text errors will be more intuitive that way.

Comment: @isherwood And even better, don't start it with it "should". For example, `it("should create an HTMLLabelElement")`. `ng g` commands add the repetitive "should" which really bothers me.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you really trying to accomplish? `createElement` always returns an HTML element as far as I know, or HTMLUnknownElement if the tag you provide isn't recognized (but is this really a possibility here?).

Comment: @ggorlen, I have a real environment and there i have already an element created. I just want to check my instance is from HTMDivElement, HTMLSpanElement or HTMLLabelElement or not. and with createElement right now i am able to recognise HTMLInputElement. It is just not recognising all the Elements and that is my concern.

Comment: If you're passing in the string `"label"` you know it's a HTMLLabelElement already. This seems like a potential [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), absent more context motivating what your goal is, because it's rather unusual to want to check which sort of element you've just created. Anyway, let's assume this makes sense. In that case, are you importing types?

Comment: Since you're running in node, _what is `document`_? Which library is that coming from? Because node doesn't come with that built-in. (And can you please show that as part of your [mcve] code? On that note, can you turn your code into an MCVE that others can run to reproduce your problem, so they can properly show how to fix it?). Also, either you're using plain jest, not ts-jest, or your code isn't showing what you're actually doing: where's the typing?

Comment: It's tagged jsdom, so I assume that's where `document` is coming from, not that there isn't a good deal of room for more explicit clarification here from OP.

Comment: Given that JSDOM is spec compliant, this test is completely meaningless. _By definition_ any standard element created with `document.createElement` will have the correct class, so whatever you're doing, this is _not_ the test to verify that because you already know JSDom is doing the right thing. So: if this is _really_ what you want to do, see answer, but I'm 100% sure it's not, and you really need to update your post to show what you're _actually_ trying to do in your real test(s). This is guaranteed [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

All of the `HTMLElement` interfaces should be available in the browser.

Since you are running Jest as a Node CLI via `ts-jest`, you have to make sure that you have a DOM `document` object available during testing. Make sure you install `jest-environment-jsdom`.

### Sample code

The following minimal configuration works.

#### index.test.ts

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

it("should create an HTMLLabelElement", async () => {
  const label: HTMLLabelElement = document.createElement("label");
  label instanceof HTMLLabelElement;
});

it("should create an HTMLInputElement", async () => {
  const input: HTMLInputElement = document.createElement("input");
  input instanceof HTMLInputElement;
});

it("should create an HTMLDivElement", async () => {
  const div: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement("div");
  div instanceof HTMLDivElement;
});
```

#### index.test.js

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

it("should create an HTMLLabelElement", async () => {
  document.createElement("label") instanceof HTMLLabelElement;
});

it("should create an HTMLInputElement", async () => {
  document.createElement("input") instanceof HTMLInputElement;
});

it("should create an HTMLDivElement", async () => {
  document.createElement("div") instanceof HTMLDivElement;
});
```

#### jest.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext"
  }
}
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "ts-jest-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "jest": "^29.6.4",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

### References

- https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/installation/
- https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

---

Here is a mock for demonstration purposes only.

```js
// Mock Jest's global `it` function:
let tests = 0, successful = 0, failed = 0;
async function it(message, test) {
  try {
    tests++;
    await test();
    successful++;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(message);
    failed++;
  }
}

(async function() {
  await it('should create an HTMLLabelElement', async() => {
    document.createElement('label') instanceof HTMLLabelElement;
  });

  await it('should create an HTMLInputElement', async() => {
    document.createElement('input') instanceof HTMLInputElement;
  });

  await it('should create an HTMLDivElement', async() => {
    document.createElement('div') instanceof HTMLDivElement;
  });
  
  console.log({ tests, successful, failed });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test against some class, explicitly import that class. In the case of the DOM, HTML classes are bound to `window`, so:

```js
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document, HTMLLabelElement } = window;

describe("some highly questionable testing", () => {
  it("is a meaningless test because we know it's true by definition", async () => {
    const label = document.createElement("label");
    console.log(label instanceof HTMLLabelElement);
  });
});
```

That said, this is a baffling weird test: *by definition* elements implement their element class in any DOM compliant implementation. By using JSDom, you are already guaranteed that this is going to be true, and testing for it gets you nothing that wasn't already true before you even ran any tests.

So I'm pretty sure you're actually testing for completely the wrong thing in whatever your real test cases are, like checking if a tag yields a standard or custom element, which you *wouldn't* do this way, and you really should have asked about whatever you actually want to do instead.

Comment: The element is not defined here. It is defined in real tsx code. But i can't share real code. So, i just shared an example to understand why the JSDOM don't support all the DOMElement definitions. So my concern was just to understand, If JSDOM can support the HTMLElement and I am not aware of it.

Comment: Then show a [mcve] that reflects your code. Also I have no idea what you mean with "JSDOM don't support all the DOMElement", it does, and if you want to use them you need to actually get them first, as shown. They're not magic global classes.